# Log4jConfigListener for logback in Spring MVC application

Tags: spring, logback

I am migrating from log4j to logback in my Spring MVC based web application. Currently, Spring's Log4jConfigListener is configure in web.xml to locate log4j.xml file as shown below:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Now, I have created logback.xml file under WEB-INF/spring folder. Is there a similar configuration in web.xml for logback also?

I don't find any LogbackConfigListener class in org.springframework.web.util package of Spring 3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Spring 3.1.x there is no way of configuring Logback with Spring using listeners.

[This blog](http://jnassef.blogspot.mx/2007/11/logback-web-configurer.html) mentions that someone [has sended the petition](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-557) to mailing list though.

Anyways, qos-ch (Les Hazlewood) has created an artifact (spring extension) for such case. Check the [github repo.](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-extensions/tree/master/spring/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/ext/spring/web)

Comment: Thanks mael. It's strange that Spring has not come up with LogbackConfigListener implementation even in Spring version 3.2.x

Comment: I am getting an issue after configuring logback using LogbackConfigListener as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631622/logbback-generating-too-many-logs-on-tomcat-console-at-startup). Could you please help me resolving it.

Comment: I don't see why, given the great logging experience Log4j has offered for decades, we all suddenly need to switch to logback. Tell me, what is it that log4j cannot do for you that makes you make the switch? Or are you just following the mud? No offense intended. Just trying to understand this sudden urge to throw away a great logging lib ;-)