# logbback generating too many logs on Tomcat console at startup

Tags: tomcat, logback

When putting logback.xml in src/main/resources/ folder of my web-application, its working fine.

However, when using [LogbackConfigListener](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-extensions/tree/master/spring/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/ext/spring/web) (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577889/log4jconfiglistener-for-logback-in-spring-mvc-application/13578156#13578156)) in web.xml to configure location of logback.xml file. The log file is generated successfully.

But, additionally there are too many DEBUG logging messages appears on the console of tomcat server. It delays tomcat server start-up time. These DEBUG messages are part of 3rd party library files like Hibernate.

logback.xml file:

```
<configuration>

<!-- Appenders -->
<appender name="util" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <File>${demo.root}/WEB-INF/app.log</File>
    <Append>true</Append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="org.springframework" level="info" />

<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="util" />
</root>

</configuration>
```

log trace is too big. I have copied some portion of it from tomcat server's start-up window:

```
00:42:09.422 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Fini
shed creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#45'
00:42:09.432 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eage
rly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0' t
o allow for resolving potential circular references
00:42:09.452 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invo
king afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'org.springframework.security.access
.vote.AffirmativeBased#0'
00:42:09.459 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Fini
shed creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.access.vote.Affirma
tiveBased#0'
00:42:09.468 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authentica
tion.ProviderManager#0'
00:42:09.476 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Crea
ting instance of bean '(inner bean)#46'
00:42:09.483 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Crea
ting instance of bean '(inner bean)#46'
00:42:09.489 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Fini
shed creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#46'
00:42:09.499 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Crea
ting instance of bean '(inner bean)#47'
00:42:09.520 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Fini
shed creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#47'
00:42:09.525 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access
.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0'
00:42:09.536 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocation
SecurityMetadataSource - Adding web access control expression 'hasRole('ROLE_ADM
IN')', for Ant [pattern='/admin.htm']
00:42:09.633 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Fini
shed creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#46'
00:42:09.638 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invo
king afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.ac
cess.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0'
00:42:09.646 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Val
idated configuration attributes
00:42:09.651 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Fini
shed creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercep
t.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0'
00:42:09.660 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initiali
zing new StandardEnvironment
00:42:09.665 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [
systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:09.670 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [
systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:09.675 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initiali
zed StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment
]
00:42:09.684 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initiali
zing new StandardEnvironment
00:42:09.689 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [
systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:09.694 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [
systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:09.699 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initiali
zed StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment
]
00:42:09.708 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initiali
zing new StandardEnvironment
00:42:09.713 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [
systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:09.718 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [
systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:09.723 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initiali
zed StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment
]
00:42:09.732 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initiali
zing new StandardEnvironment
00:42:09.737 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [
systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:09.741 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [
systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:09.747 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initiali
zed StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment
]
00:42:09.755 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initiali
zing new StandardEnvironment
00:42:09.761 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [
systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:09.765 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [
systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:09.773 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initiali
zed StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment
]
00:42:09.782 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Crea
ting filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [o
rg.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@fd9b4d,
 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@1dee0d7, or
g.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilt
er@17b650a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticat
ionFilter@267b76, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwar
eFilter@73b879, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolde
rAwareRequestFilter@1542094, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rem
emberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter@26db62, org.springframework.security.web.
authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@10d0630, org.springframework.securi
ty.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@114629, org.springframework.security.web.
access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@154145, org.springframework.security.web.acces
s.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@17035c6]
00:42:09.817 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eage
rly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1'
 to allow for resolving potential circular references
00:42:09.826 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Fini
shed creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurity
FilterChain#1'
00:42:09.834 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invo
king afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filter
Chains'
00:42:09.844 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Fini
shed creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChains'
00:42:09.851 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Crea
ting shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChain
Proxy'
00:42:09.859 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Crea
ting instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy'
00:42:09.864 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChai
ns'
00:42:09.874 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initiali
zing new StandardEnvironment
00:42:09.879 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [
systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:09.885 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [
systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:09.890 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initiali
zed StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment
]
00:42:09.897 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initiali
zing new StandardEnvironment
00:42:09.902 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [
systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:09.908 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [
systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:09.913 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initiali
zed StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment
]
00:42:09.921 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initiali
zing new StandardEnvironment
00:42:09.926 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [
systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:09.931 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [
systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:09.937 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initiali
zed StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment
]
00:42:09.950 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initiali
zing new StandardEnvironment
00:42:09.957 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [
systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:09.961 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [
systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:09.965 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initiali
zed StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment
]
00:42:09.973 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initiali
zing new StandardEnvironment
00:42:09.978 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [
systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:09.984 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [
systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:09.988 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initiali
zed StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment
]
00:42:10.001 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils - No pr
operty editor [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChainEditor] found
 for type org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain according to 'Edi
tor' suffix convention
00:42:10.017 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Init
ializing new StandardServletEnvironment
00:42:10.021 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Addi
ng [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:10.026 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Addi
ng [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:10.032 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Addi
ng [jndiProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:10.038 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Addi
ng [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:10.044 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Addi
ng [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:42:10.049 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Init
ialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams
,servletContextInitParams,jndiProperties,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
00:42:10.095 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eage
rly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy' to allow for re
solving potential circular references
00:42:10.110 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Crea
ting instance of bean '(inner bean)#48'
00:42:10.118 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Fini
shed creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#48'
00:42:10.123 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invo
king afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filter
ChainProxy'
00:42:10.133 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  o.s.s.c.h.DefaultFilterChainValidator - Che
cking whether login URL '/login.htm' is accessible with your configuration
00:42:10.146 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Chec
king match of request : '/login.htm'; against '/resources'
00:42:10.154 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Chec
king match of request : '/login.htm'; against '/admin.htm'
00:42:10.158 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.s.c.h.DefaultFilterChainValidator - No
access attributes defined for login page URL
00:42:10.164 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Fini
shed creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy'
00:42:10.172 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.Defaul
tSecurityFilterChain#0'
00:42:10.180 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.PortMa
pperImpl#0'
00:42:10.187 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.PortRe
solverImpl#0'
00:42:10.195 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.config.aut
hentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0'
00:42:10.202 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authentica
tion.ProviderManager#0'
00:42:10.210 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.contex
t.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0'
00:42:10.218 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authen
tication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy#0'
00:42:10.226 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.savedr
equest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0'
00:42:10.234 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access
.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0'
00:42:10.241 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.access.vot
e.AffirmativeBased#0'
00:42:10.249 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access
.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0'
00:42:10.256 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Crea
ting shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.
DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0'
00:42:10.264 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Crea
ting instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocat
ionPrivilegeEvaluator#0'
00:42:10.272 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access
.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0'
00:42:10.282 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eage
rly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPr
ivilegeEvaluator#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
00:42:10.298 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Fini
shed creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultW
ebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0'
00:42:10.306 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authentica
tion.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0'
00:42:10.311 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authen
tication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0'
00:42:10.319 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authentica
tion.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider#0'
00:42:10.326 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authen
tication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0'
00:42:10.335 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authen
tication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0'
00:42:10.342 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.userDetail
sServiceFactory'
00:42:10.350 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.Defaul
tSecurityFilterChain#1'
00:42:10.361 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authentica
tion.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0'
00:42:10.376 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authentica
tion.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0'
00:42:10.386 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authentica
tionManager'
00:42:10.396 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.
ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0'
00:42:10.409 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Unable
 to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org
.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@10cdec1]
00:42:10.421 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retu
rning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
00:42:10.429 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Published r
oot WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframe
work.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
00:42:10.438 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApp
licationContext: initialization completed in 27447 ms
30-Nov-2012 00:42:11 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
30-Nov-2012 00:42:11 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
30-Nov-2012 00:42:11 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 31631 ms
```

Following are the jar dependencies:

```
compile "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:$slf4jVersion"
compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$slf4jVersion"

compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:${logbackVersion}"
compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-core:${logbackVersion}"
compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-access:${logbackVersion}"
```

Comment: Can you post a trace of your logs?

Comment: None of those logs are from third party libraries, `o.s.*` logs are from the Spring Framework, anyways, your log level for "org.springframework" is set to info and I see debug messages. Is that the actual logback config?

Comment: In app.log file, only the expected logs are generated. but, I guess, some default logger is printing in tomcat console. how could I disable the default logger. Also, I am updating my post with the jar dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved the issue.

As explained [here](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-557) that LogbackConfigListener should be the first listener in web.xml file.

I was writing LogbackConfigListener below Spring's ContextLoaderListener. That sequence was working with Log4jConfigListener probably because both listeners are part of Spring framework.